# Android app that auto navigates automated telephone menus?

Tags: android, automation

So I have this number I need to call and then go through this annoying phone menu, and I have to do it every hour. I'm thinking there has to be an app for this somewhere but Googling has not turned up anything for me. To clarify what I want is an app that allows me to:

- Dial a phone number
- Wait a couple of seconds then key in some numbers
- Wait a few more seconds and key in a few more numbers
- Wait yet a few more seconds, key in more numbers, then hang up

Anyone know if there is an app out there that can do this? Having this happen on a schedule would be nice but I don't having to kick it off manually every time, just having something to navigate the menu would be great.

Comment: Given the answer provided could this be moved back to android enthusiasts? as this is not solved with an app

Comment: @JohnDemetriou I would agree 100%

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the old days there was a hardware solution, ***most hardware modems can do this for you***, especially fax modems - you had to read the manual but with the basic command set sending to the modem the sequence:

`ATDT`*SomeNumber* **,,,** 2 **,** 3 **,** 2 **,** 6 **,,**`H0`

Would dial *SomeNumber* wait for 6 seconds, (2 seconds per comma), press 2, wait 2 seconds, press 3, etc., then hang up. You can usually vary the length of time waited per comma by sending the command S8=n where n is a number of seconds.

### The Android Solution

You can also insert pauses into your mobile phone, on android phones you can insert a wait, with a prompt using **;** or `w` and a 2 second pause, *no prompt* with **,** or `p` - just edit the contact number to read:

0123456789**w**2**p**3**pp**5

**or**

0123456789 **;** 2 **,** 3 **,,** 5

To dial 0123456789 display a continue prompt, for the line to be answered, and then when you press continue send 2 & wait 2 seconds, send 3 & wait 4 seconds then send 5.